# Lifting Trial Functions for Second Order ODES

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

I have a general question here, I've been doing non-homogenous second order differential equations.

As you know, sometimes when finding the particular integral, the general trial function already appears in the complimentary function and it is necessary to modify it.

For example -

**y'' - y = e^x**

My complimentary function would be **Y = Ae^x + Be^-x**

Then looking at the RHS, my general trial function to try would be **Ce^x** but this is not possible so it would be necessary to modify it, to something like **Cxe^x**

My question is this -

I've come across some more difficult examples where it is not as clear what I should do to modify the trial function to make it work. Can someone who has a lot of experience or know how, provide me with a list of modifications that generally work for each case of trial function?

I hope I've explained clearly enough what I mean, if you need any clarifications please ask.

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I copied the rule, which might helps you, from [here](http://www.math.binghamton.edu/grads/kjones/courses/m371summer08/docs/uc.pdf) :

**The Modification Rule**

If a term in your choice for $y_p$ is already a solution to the corresponding homogeneous
equation, then multiply your choice for $y_p$ by x (or by $x^2$, if your choice corresponds a
double root).

greetings,

calculus

Answer (score 0):

This trial approach only works if the right hand side itself is a solution of a linear ODE with constant coefficients. 
That is, a sum of terms  $$p(x)\exp(ax),$$ where $a$ can also be complex, so it includes $\sin$ and $\cos$ terms. $p$ is a polynomial. If $a$ is an eigenvalue of the ODE on the left with multiplicity $m$ ($m=0$ if not eigenvalue), then the trial solution is $$x^mq(x)\exp(ax)$$ where $q(x)$ is a polynomial of the same degree as $p$ with unknown coefficients.

You can determine the trial solution for each term in the inhomogeneity separately and the sum all of them up.